# Sync SQLite DB on android studion with MySQL DB on web server

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I am developing an android app that measures the radio interface parameters of a network periodically, stores the data in SQLite DB and transfers the data stored to MySQL DB on a web server. How can I make this possible?

Comment: What is the problem? Ask some specific, do not ask for full source of programme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research on this and found only one usable option, which is to make a web service using json or xml to pull/push data between the two databases.  You could create a database link between the two, but this is not advisable.

There are numerous questions with a more detailed scope for this issue and you should be able to find one that fits your use case.  If not, ask a new question after this research with more details and what you've done so far.

Comment: what do you mean by creating a database link? please acn you explain more?

Comment: There are several methods used for keeping two remote databases synced.  These are really only best used inside a vpn with consistent and constant connections, not in a situation where mobile service could be dropped.  I don't remember where, but I found a library for an early version of Android that did this, but there were numerous problems with the library and I don't know if it would even function on newer versions of Android.  You want to use a web service to accomplish this, but you'll need to do some research on how you want to accomplish it.  There are a multitude of options available.

Comment: I will inform you when I find something good. What I am trying to do now is how to establish a communication protocol between the android application and the Web server. By this, I am saying that i want to model a communication diagram between the two databases, like saying that when the data is sent to the web server as a request, the android service would have to wait for a specific amount of time to receive the response from the web server and if this doesn't happen, the request would be sent again. This is very crucial because it would not be every time that the user would be online.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. The current project I'm working on I only need to push data up to the web server, but I haven't gotten to the stage of building that yet, and have just done a lot of research.